# Stripping a Windows path prefix

Tags: windows, path, rust

I am trying to strip a prefix from Windows path. I attempted to do this using the [`strip_prefix`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.strip_prefix) method but it fails. You can try it out at the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=924c55d1b2f3f4a1e813e0fa3e65bdac). I was not able to get any reasonable details as to why this failed even with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full`.

```
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let pwd = Path::new(r#"C:\Users\me"#);
    let path = Path::new(r#"C:\Users\me\site"#);
    let result = path.strip_prefix(pwd).map_err(|_| ());
    println!("Result: {:?}", result); // Result: Err(())
    path.strip_prefix(pwd).unwrap();
}
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Result with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full`:

```
Result: Err(())
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: StripPrefixError(())', src/libcore/result.rs:997:5
stack backtrace:

0: 0x55f339d5eb53 - std::sys::unix::backtrace::tracing::imp::unwind_backtrace::hf8722b0178fb1b63
    at src/libstd/sys/unix/backtrace/tracing/gcc_s.rs:39
1: 0x55f339d5aa68 - std::sys_common::backtrace::_print::hc40139e5f1d656ee
    at src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:70
2: 0x55f339d5daa2 - std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}::h993d43465919c16a
    at src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:58
    at src/libstd/panicking.rs:200
3: 0x55f339d5d814 - std::panicking::default_hook::h73d2c2ec3d9ba5a4
    at src/libstd/panicking.rs:215
4: 0x55f339d5e100 - std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook::h744417edfe714d72
    at src/libstd/panicking.rs:478
5: 0x55f339d5dc81 - std::panicking::continue_panic_fmt::h3557b3c3fa21b47b
    at src/libstd/panicking.rs:385
6: 0x55f339d5db65 - rust_begin_unwind
    at src/libstd/panicking.rs:312
7: 0x55f339d6e0cc - core::panicking::panic_fmt::h74ee8034b317ceed
    at src/libcore/panicking.rs:85
8: 0x55f339d536fd - core::result::unwrap_failed::h3406097ad0bd8fc9
    at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858/src/libcore/macros.rs:16
9: 0x55f339d53429 - <core::result::Result<T, E>>::unwrap::hac51cf7638922ce6
    at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858/src/libcore/result.rs:798
10: 0x55f339d53e89 - g::main::h131de6fc3bc2b7fb
    at src/main.rs:8
11: 0x55f339d538df - std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}::h68e0b763dc36e392
    at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858/src/libstd/rt.rs:64
12: 0x55f339d5db52 - std::panicking::try::do_call::h7a0381557c6c2cee
    at src/libstd/rt.rs:49
    at src/libstd/panicking.rs:297
13: 0x55f339d5faa9 - __rust_maybe_catch_panic
    at src/libpanic_unwind/lib.rs:92
14: 0x55f339d5e655 - std::rt::lang_start_internal::he0d8d06abc6f912f
    at src/libstd/panicking.rs:276
    at src/libstd/panic.rs:388
    at src/libstd/rt.rs:48
15: 0x55f339d538b8 - std::rt::lang_start::h565ec575e9c57feb
    at /rustc/2aa4c46cfdd726e97360c2734835aa3515e8c858/src/libstd/rt.rs:64
16: 0x55f339d53ec9 - main
17: 0x7f59a6820412 - __libc_start_main
18: 0x55f339d531fd - _start
19: 0x0 - <unknown>
```

Comment: Have you actually tried this on Windows? The playground runs on Linux, on which those paths are just two regular files, without a directory component, and neither is a base of the other. Your example [does work with forward slashes on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=302408d10517429e8bc9f901e37a3c9e).

Comment: Generally when I ask "does this tool used by thousands have an obvious bug or am I missing something," I start from the assumption that I am missing something :). I think @mcarton has it right.

Comment: *I was not able to get any reasonable details* —  Why are you deliberately throwing away any error details with `.map_err(|_| ())`?

Comment: I've tested — this code works perfectly fine **on Windows**. It prints out `Result: Ok("site")`.

Comment: @Shepmaster that was also my first thought, but to be fair, even with the `map_err`, the message isn't that useful, as it only prints `Err(StripPrefixError(()))`.

Comment: @mcarton I didn't. I don't have Windows machine at hand currently.

Comment: @chucksmash That was my assumption as well. That's why I asked.

Comment: @Shepmaster Just as a demonstration of the result. Unwrapping example and output was there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the document of [`std::path::Path`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html) says:

> This type supports a number of operations for inspecting a path, including breaking the path into its components (**separated by `/` on Unix and by either `/` or `\` on Windows**), extracting the file name, determining whether the path is absolute, and so on.

(emphasis is mine)

This means that on Linux, `\` will not be recognized as a path separator, and therefore, `C:\Users\me` and `C:\\Users\me\site` are just filenames, in the current directory. On Linux, `\` is indeed not a special character in filenames:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ cd foo
$ touch 'C:\Users\me'
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 martin martin 0 Apr 14 01:47 'C:\Users\me'
```

As the Playground runs on Linux ([as hinted by the fact that there is no deployment information for Windows](https://github.com/integer32llc/rust-playground/tree/master/deployment), although it might technically be possible to host it on Windows as well), your code cannot work there.

However on Windows, [it works as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55665098/stripping-a-windows-path-prefix?noredirect=1#comment98025488_55665098).

Comment: *As the Playground runs on Linux* — as the primary maintainer of the Playground, I can assert this is true. *technically be possible to host it on Windows* — that's an unwelcome can of worms at the moment ;-)